# How to restrict who can download my app in google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I've developed an enterprise android app which targets specific set of users. Is there a way to restrict the app not to be downloadable by other persons.
Something like asking for a password before downloading the app, so that I can distribute the password to my specific app users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use play store private channel feature which allows you to control which users or user groups can download the apps. [Please have a read](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en).

Comment: It is now called "Private Apps", which requires setting up Android Device Policy for your organization, and adding employees' devices, then your private apps will be available on their managed Play Store app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restrict exactly download and install the app but nobody prevents you from asking for the password after the application starts.

To stay civilized, I would recommend to provide at least some useful functionality for all users as well, and do not forget to document in the description about the password.